# OpenSSL Padding Oracle vulnerability (CVE-2016-2107) + Nginx

Tags: ubuntu, openssl, nginx

I was trying [Qualys SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html) test and It told me that the server is vulnerable to `OpenSSL Padding Oracle vulnerability (CVE-2016-2107)`. I googled around on how to fix this, and although the OpenSSL version installed on my system (Ubuntu 14.04) should be patched for that according to this [link](https://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-2959-1/) I was still getting this error.

I tried upgrading OpenSSL but it was already the newest version, so I installed manually a newer version following the instructions [here](http://www.miguelvallejo.com/updating-to-openssl-1-0-2g-on-ubuntu-server-12-04-14-04-lts-to-stop-cve-2016-0800-drown-attack/) which went fine, but that didn't fix anything. Looking at the info from Nginx, It seems it still runs with the previous version:

```
nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.10.2
built with OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014 (running with OpenSSL 1.0.2g-fips 1 Mar 2016)
```

while OpenSSL has clearly been updated:

```
openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2j 26 Sep 2016
```

Any idea how to get all this sorted out?

Note that yes, I did restart Nginx, I even tried `sudo service nginx upgrade` and even rebooted the server.

Answer (score 1):

You need to [**build**](https://nginx.org/en/docs/configure.html) `ngnix` with the `openSSL 1.0.1f` version

The `configure` command might look like this:

```
./configure --with-http_ssl_module --with-openssl=/path/to/openssl 1.0.1f
```